# Remove the number of posts displayed in wp_list_categories()

Tags: categories

When I use wp_list_categories(), it results in the number of posts in a category being shown, how do I hide the number?

For example: I have xyz category, it has 3 posts, the result will be:

```
xyz(3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `wp_list_categories()` doesn't show post count, because `show_count` is set to `false`, check arguments passed into `wp_list_categories()`.